# MAODV : has no member named

Tags: c++, ns2

```
void AODV::rt_resolve(Packet *p) {
    struct hdr_cmn *ch = HDR_CMN(p);
    struct hdr_ip *ih = HDR_IP(p);
    aodv_rt_entry *rt;
    ch->xmit_failure_ = aodv_rt_failed_callback;
    ch->xmit_failure_data_ = (void*) this;
    rt = rtable.rt_lookup(ih->daddr());

    if(rt == 0) {
      rt = rtable.rt_add(ih->daddr());
    }

    if(rt->rt_flags == RTF_UP) {
       assert(rt->rt_hops != INFINITY2);
     #ifdef PREDICTION
        double breakTime = 2000.0;
        if (ch->num_forwards() != 0 && ch->next_hop_ == index){
        Node *currentNode = Node::get_node_by_address(index);
        breakTime = currentNode->getTime(ch->prev_hop_);

     if (breakTime < 2000.0 && breakTime > CURRENT_TIME 
      && (breakTime - CURRENT_TIME < PREDICTION_TIME_FOR_UNICAST) 
      && (rt->rt_prevnode_warning == 0)){              
        //printf("\nPREDICTION:: at %.9f on node %d prev node %d , dst %d, will break at %.9f\n", CURRENT_TIME, index, ch->prev_hop_, ih->daddr(), breakTime); 
        sendLPW(ch->prev_hop_, breakTime);
        rt->rt_prevnode_warning ++;
    }
}
#endif
forward(rt, p, NO_DELAY);
}
```

In the above code of MAODV i am getting following error

```
In member function ‘void AODV::rt_resolve(Packet*)’:
 aodv/aodv.cc:569:34: error: ‘class Node’ has no member named ‘getTime’
```

Comment: Your class `Node` has no member named `getTime`. Please show us the definition of `Node`.

Comment: This is from the MAODV code and its part of aodv.cc and getTime is used in this particular block of code. Not in other headers files that are included.

Comment: It looks like your build environment is not healthy.  From [this header](http://read.pudn.com/downloads182/sourcecode/comm/849441/maodv-code/node.h__.htm), class `Node` certainly does have the correct function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy [node.h](http://read.pudn.com/downloads182/sourcecode/comm/849441/maodv-code/node.h__.htm) to the directory

> ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/common

As the function is defined in the "node.h" of MAODV code but not in simple "node.h" that is already present.